# Get object in json flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart, fromjson

I have this JSON output (using Chopper library)

> {"status":"success","error_message":[],"abc":[{"id":"124"},{"id":"125"}]}

How can I get the id in object abc ?

```
Response response = await _repo.submitData(title, description);

var abcResponse = ABCResponse.fromJson(response.body);
    if (abcResponse.status == 'success') {
       // I want print the latest id
  }
}
```

**ABCResponse**

```
part 'abc_response.g.dart';

    @JsonSerializable()
    class ABCResponse extends BaseResponse {
      var abc = new List<ABC>();
      ABCResponse();

      factory ABCResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
          _$ABCResponse(json);
      Map<String, dynamic> toJason() => _$WABCResponseToJson(this);
    }
```

**ABC**

```
 @JsonSerializable()
class ABC {

  ABC();
  var id;
}
```

**Edit**

```
 Response response = await _repository.submitData(title, description);

    var abcResponse = ABCResponse.fromJson(response.body);
    if (abcResponse.status == 'success') {
      var user = json.decode(abcResponse.abc.toString());
      print(user);   // it printing null value
    }
```

Comment: @GhostCatsaysReinstateMonica sorry, what is not clear here? I want to get the latest id, which is 124 in the if block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example code to decode the given json and extract id.

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() 
{
  var jsonString = '{"status":"success","error_message":[],"abc":[{"id":"124"},{"id":"125"}]}'; // just store input json to a variable.
  var user = json.decode(jsonString.toString()); // convert input to string if it isn't already
  print(user['abc'][0]['id']); // complex(nested) json parsing; prints 124
}
```

use `json.decode()` to convert json string to a Map.

1. `user['abc']` will give you `[{id: 124}, {id: 125}]`
2. `user['abc'][0]` will give you `{id: 124}, {id: 125}` i.e. extract
   0th element of the input List.
3. Finally `['abc'][0]['id']` will give you the id: `124`.

Comment: I getting null value.

Comment: There might be some syntax error on your side bcoz the code works fine on https://dartpad.dartlang.org/

Comment: Please share response of `print(abcResponse.toString())` just after `var abcResponse = ABCResponse.fromJson(response.body);`

Comment: Please share the output of print in my previous comment

Comment: It prints `Instance of 'ABCResponse'`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201796/discussion-between-john-joe-and-futurejj).